# How can javascript collect values from the same classname in select-option?

Tags: javascript, html

I made table for the individual summation of the same classnames as like '30', '60'...

```
<td>
    <select onchange='summation()' class='30' name='Cr'>
        <option value=0>>15.0</option>
        <option value=1>10.0/15.0</option>
        <option value=2><5.0</option>
        <option value=3>5.0/10.0</option>
</td>
<td>
    <select onchange='summation()' class='30' name='WBC'>
        <option value=0><2000</option>
        <option value=1>2000~4000</option>
        <option value=2> >10000</option>
        <option value=3>4000~10000</option>
</td>
<td>
    <select onchange='summation()' class='90' name='post-BUN'>
        <option value=0>>24</option>
        <option value=1><20</option>
        <option value=2>20/24</option>
</td>
<td>
    <select onchange='summation()' class='180' name='HBsAg'>
        <option value=0>posi</option>
        <option value=3>nega</option>
</td>
```

In Browser, that code's displaying below
[image]
I made javascript as below. Classname ='30' values are the collection of object.

```
function summation() {
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("30");
    ???????????
 document.getElementById("30").innerHTML = x.valueOf();
```

How can I get the summation of the classname="30" from the that code?

When option selected, I want the sum of the values of the classname '30'. In here, 3 and 2 selected, the sum will be 5. I want That sum "5"

Comment: Can you eloborate your requirement?? What actually you need to achieve from the above code given??

Comment: Do you want to have the summation of each selected option's value ?

Comment: Yes, Vincent Valves. Summation of selected options' values

Comment: You said you want "summation of the classname="30""...but summation() runs on all the selects, but only 2 of them have classname=30. So you want to collect all the selects, or just the "30" ones? It's a bit confusing

Comment: Above code, only 2  values. But in real code, the number of same classname='30'  are about 20.

Comment: Ok I posted an answer with what I think you want, but if it's not right you'll have to clarify the exact requirements a bit further.

Comment: I used Id name same as the classname for the fast recognition.

Comment: Ok. And your point is? have you looked at my answer? Does it help you?

Comment: When option selected, I want the sum of the values of the classname '30'. In Here, 3 and 2 selected, the sum will be 5. I want That sum "5".

Comment: Ok. Well that's what my answer does, below. Did you look? You can run the demo.

Comment: P.S. you should have given that example in the original question, it would have been much clearer! I've added it for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is probably what you want, but it's a tiny bit unclear from the requirements. (I'm unsure why you run the "summation" function on the last two selects when you are not including them in the calculation.)

From a code point of view, `querySelectorAll` is used to find all elements with the same class. The advantage of this vs `getElementsByClassName` is that you can then easily loop over the items with a `forEach` as I have done.

Note that I had to alter your class names slightly because JavaScript complains about an invalid selector when the class name starts with a number. But this is a trivial change.

```js
function summation() {
  var x = document.querySelectorAll(".select30");
  var total = 0;

  x.forEach(function(item) {
    total += parseInt(item.value);
  });
  console.log("Total: " + total);
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <select onchange='summation()' class='select30' name='Cr'>
        <option value=0>&gt;15.0</option>
        <option value=1>10.0/15.0</option>
        <option value=2>&lt;5.0</option>
            <option value=3>5.0/10.0</option>
    </td>
    <td>
      <select onchange='summation()' class='select30' name='WBC'>
        <option value=0>
          <2000</option>
            <option value=1>2000~4000</option>
            <option value=2> &gt;10000</option>
            <option value=3>4000~10000</option>
    </td>
    <td>
      <select onchange='summation()' class='select90' name='post-BUN'>
        <option value=0>>24</option>
        <option value=1>
          <20</option>
            <option value=2>20/24</option>
    </td>
    <td>
      <select onchange='summation()' class='select180' name='HBsAg'>
        <option value=0>posi</option>
        <option value=3>nega</option>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Oh, Thank you! Working! YOU are right! IF Classname's first letter is number, doesn't work!!

Answer (score 1):

After agreeing with ADyson and trying to do without a class name and but with data attribute here is what I have done.

```js
const selectItems = document.querySelectorAll("select"); // selecting all select elements

selectItems.forEach(selectItem => { // looping through all select elements
  selectItem.addEventListener("change", function() { // calling a function on change
    let dataNumber = this.dataset.num;
    summation(dataNumber); // passing the value of data-num to find next elements which has same data-num 
  });
});

function summation(dataNumber) {
  const allElements = document.querySelectorAll("[data-num]"); // selecting all elements that has data-num attribute
  const allElementsWithSameDataNumber = []; // to store all elements that has same data-num
  allElements.forEach(select => {
    if (select.dataset.num === dataNumber) {
      allElementsWithSameDataNumber.push(select);
    }
  });

  // Calculating the value of same data-number's select elements
  let value = 0;
  allElementsWithSameDataNumber.forEach(cur => {
    value = parseInt(cur.value) + value;
  });
  console.log(value);
}
```

```html
<select data-num="30" name="Cr">
      <option value="10">10</option>
      <option value="1">1</option>
    </select>

    <select data-num="30" name="WBC">
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="2"> >2</option>
    </select>

    <select data-num="180" name="WBC">
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="2"> >2</option>
    </select>

    <select data-num="180" name="WBC">
      <option value="8">8</option>
      <option value="2"> >2</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: I'm a beginner programmer, so I don't know exactly how to operate your code.

Comment: I have done it with the data-num attribute. Select elements must have this attribute. So if the data-num attribute is the same with other select elements, after selecting an item, all values will be added and the total will be console logged.